# How to pass props to child component in Next.JS 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-props

I'm having some trouble getting NextJS to work with props and passing them through components. This may be a bit more of a React approach so maybe it doesn't work here but I've tried googling and not many results come back with how to do it.
Basically what I'm trying to do is simply pass a useState and setUseState value from my parent to child in order to update inside the child onClick.

However there is an error that seems to be occurring on the Prop type when I pass props through. The only way to avoid it seems to be by using `(props: any)` however I don't want to do this as it isn't Type safe.

Is what I'm trying to do possible in NextJS or is there a different way to do it? I had a look at `getInitial/Static/ServerProps` but couldn't get those to work either.

Admittedly I haven't got much experience with Next so perhaps it's a skill issue.

Hopefully that was clear enough, happy to add more detail I probably missed something crucial it's just been plaguing me all day!

Thanks for any help.

**Parent component**

```
'use client';
import { useState } from 'react';
import ChildComponent from './childComponent/page';

export default function ParentComponent() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('hello world')
  return <ChildComponent value={value} setValue={setValue}/>
}
```

**Child component**

```
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react'

interface Props {
  value: string
  setValue: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>
}

const ChildComponent = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span onClick={() => props.setValue('hello moon')}>{props.value}</span>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ChildComponent
```

**Error**

```
.next/types/app/childComponent/page.ts:26:13
Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<Props, keyof PageProps, "default">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
  Property 'value' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

  24 | 
  25 | // Check the prop type of the entry function
> 26 | checkFields<Diff<PageProps, FirstArg<TEntry['default']>, 'default'>>()
     |             ^
```

**layout.tsx**

```
import ...

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Title',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className=' bg-pink-300 h-screen w-screen content-center justify-center items-center flex'>
      <body className={`${inter.className} h-screen w-screen justify-center items-center flex`}>
      
        {children}
      
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

next.config.js is default

I have tried with `const Component = (props: Props)`, const `Component: React.FC<Props> = (props)`, `Interface/Type { value: any, setValue: any }` and all permutations of these to no avail.

The app also builds perfectly fine when running npm run dev and the usestate can be updated but just when running npm run build does it fail.

[image]

To the best of my knowledge it looks like the only types that can be passed are those that can be made are those that are valid in an index interface `An index signature parameter type must be 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or a template literal type.`

```
interface Props {
  [key: string | number ]: string
}
```

Because of this I am going to leave it as (props: any) for now...

Edit 2:

Attempted with the components folder mentioned by Sachin and it's working perfectly. Perhaps you can do it the other way too but my brain is too small or it's just not possible.

Here is the classes and dir layout for anyone's future reference...

**Parent**

```
'use client';
import { useState } from 'react'
import { ChildComponent } from '@/components/';
 
export default function Page() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('hello world')
  return <ChildComponent setValue={setValue} value={value} />
}
```

```
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react'

interface Props {
  value: string
  setValue: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>
}

const ChildComponent = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span onClick={() => props.setValue('hello moon')}>{props.value}</span>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ChildComponent
```

Thanks to all!

[image]

Comment: IMO, you have created your childComponent as a next.js page, create a components directory outside the app directory and put the childComponent there.

Comment: Agree with @SachinSom, in the app folder only your pages should sit. The rest should be outside of the app directory. So move the assets and components outside of /app to their separate folder, then check if that solves the issue.

Comment: Updated with the solution thanks to all, the solution was the components folder method, i didn't know you could do that so thanks for teaching me a new trick @SachinSom!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

Use the components folder, the directory layout should be like

```
root
|
├- app
|  ├ page.tsx
|  ├ layout.tsx
|  └ ...
|
├- components
|  ├ childComponent
|  | └ ChildComponent.tsx
|  └ index.ts (optional)
└ ...
```

**Page.tsx** it should simply be:

```
'use client';
import { useState } from 'react'
import { ChildComponent } from '@/components/';
 
export default function Page() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('hello world')
  return <ChildComponent setValue={setValue} value={value} />
}
```

**ChildComponent.tsx** (with props):

```
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react'

interface Props {
  value: string
  setValue: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>
}

const ChildComponent = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span onClick={() => props.setValue('hello moon')}>{props.value}</span>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ChildComponent
```

See my original question for more detail if needed!